# Photoshop javascript, how to select contents of a layer

Tags: photoshop-scripting, javascript

Is there a method for the following function (mac) Command-click on thumbnail in layer panel? (So all non empty pixels get selected in specified layer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that uses scriptlistener code to select all the pixels in the current layer

```
function selectLayerPixels()
{
  // =======================================================
  var id710 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
  var desc168 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id711 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref128 = new ActionReference();
  var id712 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
  var id713 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
  ref128.putProperty( id712, id713 );
  desc168.putReference( id711, ref128 );
  var id714 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var ref129 = new ActionReference();
  var id715 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
  var id716 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
  var id717 = charIDToTypeID( "Trsp" );
  ref129.putEnumerated( id715, id716, id717 );
  desc168.putReference( id714, ref129 );
  executeAction( id710, desc168, DialogModes.NO );
}
```